# How to place Items when converting from Figma to code?

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, grid, figma

I’m new to figma , and sometimes when I look at a figma design there are elements which should be placed in grid or flexbox , but by doing so sometimes the design is not 100% accurate , do you set all the elements as “absolute” position so you can have that perfect positioning ? , and if so how that plays out when you try to make the webpage responsive ?

Comment: This seems to be a rather general question. Is there a specific example you could show, including the code you have attempted to copy the design? In general for responsiveness % units are better than fixed ones like px, but it depends on exactly what is required as the viewport changes.

Comment: My question is general , some customers provide a figam design and ask for a pixel perfect code similar to the component , of course its easy to achieve this by setting every element to an absloute positioning but i know this is a bad practice  , if i set some elenets in a grid containers or a flexbox there will be no way a pixel perfect desing but still its better and more responsive , so i was wondering what others who work in figma do ?